# New-PnPSite gives error with paramter -TimeZone

Tags: sharepoint-online, team-sites, provisioning

I try to create a SharePoint group-based modern teamsite by powershell, but get an error. What I am doing wrong?

```
Connect-PnPOnline -ManagedIdentity -Url $adminCenterURL

New-PnPSite -Type TeamSite -Title "someName" -Alias "someName" -Owner $owners -Lcid 1043 -TimeZone UTCPLUS0100_AMSTERDAM_BERLIN_BERN_ROME_STOCKHOLM_VIENNA
```

**ERROR: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.**

When I remove parameter -TimeZone it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new site, you need SharePoint admin permission. But when you want to set time zone of a site, you need permissions for this site. SharePoint admin does not mean has permissions for all sites.

So, first create a new site, then change the time zone of this site with enough permission.

Comment: But why they add parameter "TimeZone" to command "New-PnPSite"? I expect they build it and should work.